# Issues with jQuery .live() event binding!

Tags: jquery

I am facing a very wierd issue with jQuery live event binding.

```
  
$(document).ready(function (){
 $('select').live('change', function () {
  // works fine 
 }); 
 $('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
  // doesn't work! 
 });

});
```

If I switch the order,

```
 
$(document).ready(function (){
 $('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
  // works fine 
 });

 $('select').live('change', function () {
  // doesn't work! 
 });

});
```

In other words, the problem is only the first live binding actually goes through and works fine! I am not sure if this is even a logical issue!

any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the latest jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a syntax error:

```
$('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
    // works fine 
});

$('select').live('change', function () {
    // should be working now
});
```

Note the `);` that I've added.

**Edit** now that you've updated your question, my answer doesn't make sense. I'm going to guess, however, that you've got *additional* code *between* these two lines, and that code is raising an error, which stops the second `live()` call from being called.

That's just a guess, though....

Comment: Yeah, I fixed the question - if that was the problem, it wouldnt have worked at all :). Yes, I do have code in the middle, but remember if I switch the order it everything works fine. So, I don't think it's the code cause an error.

Comment: @OneDeveloper: you said it's the second one that fails, no matter which one that is. That tells me it's getting an error *between* when the first one executes and the second one. I suggest you use something like Firebug which will report any Javascript errors that you might otherwise miss.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close parentheses. Here's a [working example](http://jsbin.com/iyiha/edit):

```
$(function() {
    $('select').live('change', function() {
        alert('change');
    }); 
    $('input:checkbox').live('click', function() {
        alert('click'); 
    }); 
}); ​
```

Comment: I must have forgotten this during copying the code. This is not really the problem.

Comment: @OneDeveloper, I don't know if this is not really the problem but did you follow the link I posted? It works! So I don't see a reason for downvote.

Comment: do you think it wouldve worked at all if it was a syntax problem? I am sorry for the downvote, but I was trying to say this is not the answer.